# Soit... soit... avec plus de deux éléments

Tags: grammaire

Je voudrais faire une liste de possibilités mais je ne sais pas comment écrire cela.

Je crois que je peux bien dire "On va manger soit de la viande, soit du poisson".

Mais comment je fais si je veux ajouter une troisième (ou plus) option, disons légumes?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to use three consecutive "soit"s, just as you can use  three consecutive "ni"s in a negative structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rien n'interdit de multiplier les *soit* autant de fois que nécessaire :

> On va manger soit de la viande, soit du poisson, soit des légumes, soit des fruits.

Answer (score 4):

Il est possible de séparer les éléments de la liste par une virgule et de terminer par un "ou" entre les deux derniers éléments.

Par exemple :

> On va manger de la viande, du poisson, ou des légumes.